# How can I delay allowing routes to be looked up until dynamic routes have been populated?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm writing an Angular application, and want to dynamically create routes. This is to centralise where configuration is done. Instead of having one configuration for routing, and another for a table of contents, I decided to try integrating the routing information into the tree structure (PrimeNG `TreeNode` structure) making up the table of contents. Something like:

```
export class TableOfContentsService {
  private tree: TreeNode[] = [
    {
      label: 'First Chapter',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'First Section',
          data: {
            route: {path: 'first-section', component: FirstSectionComponent},
          }
        },
    }
  ];
}
```

I'm then extracting the `route` from each node in the tree, and essentially doing `this.router.push(extractedRoutes)` in the constructor of the routing `NgModule`. This worked fine.

**The problem is**, the "extracting the `route` from each node in the tree" step is now asynchronous. I need to wait for some data to load before I can extract the routes. The issue this is causing now is if a user was on one of the dynamically loaded pages (`/first-section` for example) and then refreshed the page, Angular attempts to lookup `first-section` immediately, and fails because that route hasn't been loaded yet.

I thought `CanActivate` would help here, so I tried (`routesArePatched$` is just a  `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` that emits `true` when the routes have been loaded):

```
@Injectable()
export class WaitForRoutesToLoad implements CanActivateChild {
  constructor(
    private service: TableOfContentsService,
  ) {
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service.routesArePatched$.pipe(
      filter((arePatched) => arePatched),
      map(() => true),
    );
  }
}
```

I then put `WaitForRoutesToLoad` in the `canActivateChild` array of the parent route.

The problem with this is though, Angular attempts to resolve the route before calling `canActivateChild`, so on refresh, `canActivateChild` is never even called, and then the route lookup fails, and then the routes are loaded fractions of a second after that. `canActivateChild` is called on navigation after that (so I know it's hooked up fine), but that doesn't help me if the only thing I need it for is the initial load.

I also tried a `Resolver` that looked essentially the same as the above `WaitForRoutesToLoad`, but it suffered from the same issue that it's never even called if the routes can't be resolved right away.

---

Is there a way to instruct Angular to wait for some asyncronous condition before even attempting to resolve a route?

Comment: Framing challenge: why declare the routes in the component and then push them into the router? Why not declare them in the router and then read them in the component?

Comment: Also, yes, you can use the [`Resolve` interface](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to achieve what you're asking. I can write up an answer if you still want to pursue that route.

Comment: @DM My goal was to make it more straightforward to edit the tree. If some information is in the routing module, and some is in the service, that's two place to edit data. I thought having it all in one place would make things easier in the long run, but it's been a bit of a mess so far. I would like to see how `Resolve` could be used here though, because I can't even get its method to get called if the route doesn't exist.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I don't know that `Resolve` is the way to go here. You'd need an empty-pathed prefix route at the root level to run the resolver against and that doesn't feel right. I'll play around with it a bit...

Comment: @DM Thanks for looking into it, but don't worry now. I've decided having the `path` in two places is far less of an evil than the mess that this became. It was nice in theory, but not in practice. I've converted everything back (with the dynamic routes on a separate branch just in case), but this already feels better. Thanks again.